# Javascript slug function with non-latin chars

Tags: javascript, regex, slug

I am writing a function to make slug from input.

```
var vslug = function (str) {
  str = str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
  str = str.toLowerCase();
  var vregex = /(?:\.([^.]+))?$/;
  var filename  = str.replace(vregex.exec(str)[0],'');
  var extension = vregex.exec(str)[1];
  var from = "àáäâèéëêìíïîıòóöôùúüûñçşğ·/,:;";
  var to   = "aaaaeeeeiiiiioooouuuuncsg_____";
  for (var i = 0; i < from.length; i++) {
    console.log('before ' + str);
    str = filename.replace(new RegExp(from[i], 'g'), to[i]);
    console.log('after ' + str);
  }
  str = str.replace(/[^a-z0-9 _-]/g, '')
  .replace(/\s+/g, '_')
  .replace(/-+/g, '_');
  if (typeof extension !== "undefined") {
    return str+'.'+extension;
  } else {
    return str;
  }
};
```

I can't make this part - I gone blind. Any help is appreciated..

```
  var from = "àáäâèéëêìíïîıòóöôùúüûñçşğ·/,:;";
  var to   = "aaaaeeeeiiiiioooouuuuncsg_____";
  for (var i = 0; i < from.length; i++) {
    console.log('before ' + str);
    str = filename.replace(new RegExp(from[i], 'g'), to[i]);
    console.log('after ' + str);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filename` is not changed - the variable names the same string, and the string cannot be modified. As such, each loop starts working on the *original* string again when it uses `filename.replace..`.

Instead, eliminate `filename` (or integrate it fully) and use `str = str.replace..`

```
str = str.replace(vregex.exec(str)[0],'');
for (var i = 0; i < from.length; i++) {
  str = str.replace(new RegExp(from[i], 'g'), to[i]);
  // ^-- next loop gets new value
}
```

(Also, this could be handled with a replacement function and a map instead of n-loops and there might be a Unicode library for JavaScript available..)

---

An approach using a map and a replacement function might look like:

```
// Specify map somewhere reusable; can be built from paired arrays for simplicity.
var replacements = {"à":"a", "á":"a", .. ";":"_"}
// Object.keys is ES5, shim as needed. e.g. result: [à;á..]
var alternation = "[" + Object.keys(replacements).join("") + "]"
// This regex will match all characters we are trying to match.
var regex = new Regex(alternation, "g")

str = str.replace(regex, function (m) { 
    var r = replacements[m]
    return r || m        
})
```

See [String.replace(regex, function)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: Thank you :) Works. But to take it further, I'd be happy if you give a light for map use. I'd use it if you may give a start...

Comment: @YahyaE I've added an example. YMMV.

Comment: using non-latin chars as keys in object is considered invalid, also can have issues with capital letters.

Comment: @venimus It is 100% valid to have latin characters as keys - as *any* string can be used as key. Any issues with unicode strings in JavaScript (in implementations, of which there are several: just none that affect this code) is a secondary consideration and does not change ECMAScript's definition. If someone considers such "invalid", then such is a personal opinion.

Comment: @venimus See ["6.1.7 .. Properties are identified using key values. A property key value is either an ECMAScript String value or a Symbol value. **All String and Symbol values, including the empty string, are valid as property keys.** A property name is a property key that is a String value."](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html), which is quite clear on the topic.

Comment: @user2864740 thanx for clarification. What I meant by "considered invalid" is based on the reports of some linters, probably based on certain JS engine implementations (probably pre-ES5 ones).